# delete all the other columns

Tags: excel, vb6, excel-2007

This code is a macro that searches for some values in the different sheets and remove their columns. But what should I do if I want to delete **all the other** columns **instead** and keep them that I'm searching for?

with other words, I want the macro to do the opposite?

code:

```
    Sub Level()
Dim calcmode As Long
Dim ViewMode As Long
Dim myStrings As Variant
Dim FoundCell As Range
Dim I As Long
Dim wsSkador As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
With Application
    calcmode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With
    myStrings = Array("Apple", "Banan")
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
With ws.Range("A6:EE6")

        For I = LBound(myStrings) To UBound(myStrings)
            Do
               Set FoundCell = .Find(What:=myStrings(I), _
                                           After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                                           LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                           LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                           SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                           SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                           MatchCase:=False)

                If FoundCell Is Nothing Then
                    Exit Do
                Else
                    FoundCell.EntireColumn.Delete
                End If
            Loop
        Next I
End With
    Next ws
    End Sub
```

Comment: if you post your code here you will have more luck, as sites like megashares are often blocked by corporate policies.

Comment: Instead of posting the Excel-file, you should show some code, explain what the code is doing, what you want it to do instead and what you have tried so far to get it working. Otherwise I'm afraid you won't receive any help (and I very much doubt that anyone wants to open some random Excel-file downloaded from megashare...).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Now is my code in question also.

Comment: hi Polynomial, cdeszaq, AakashM, Stuart Dunkeld, Ray, can you please oppen my question? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I would take is to loop through the Columns, searching each in turn in the pattern array, deleteing when not found.

Here's a rewoked verion of your Sub:

```
Sub Level()
    Dim calcmode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long
    Dim myStrings As Variant
    Dim FoundCell As Range
    Dim I As Long
    Dim wsSkador As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim Found As Boolean
    Dim DeleteRange As Range

    On Error GoTo EH

    With Application
        calcmode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    myStrings = Array("a", "s")
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set DeleteRange = Nothing
        For Each cl In ws.[A6:EE6]
            If cl <> "" Then
                Found = False
                For I = LBound(myStrings) To UBound(myStrings)
                    If LCase$(cl.Formula) Like LCase$("*" & myStrings(I) & "*") Then
                        Found = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next I
                If Not Found Then
                    If DeleteRange Is Nothing Then
                        Set DeleteRange = cl
                    Else
                        Set DeleteRange = Union(DeleteRange, cl)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next cl
        If Not DeleteRange Is Nothing Then
            DeleteRange.EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next ws
    With Application
        .Calculation = calcmode
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
Exit Sub
EH:
    Debug.Assert
    'Resume  ' Uncomment this to retry the offending code
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank u Chris! Sorry, I got the error message "Object variable or With-blok variable not set" and the line (DeleteRange.EntireColumn.Delete) is selected.

Comment: That will happen if no non matching columns are found (`DeleteRange` will be = `Nothing`)  Wrap that line in `If Not DeleteRange Is Nothing Then`

Comment: Sorry Chris for the inconvenience I changed (If DeleteRange Is Nothing Then) to (If Not DeleteRange Is Nothing Then), but it's the same error message.

Comment: To better understand whats going wrong, see my edited code.  I added an error handler and break.  Add `DeleteRange` to the watch list to examine what it refers to when the code errors.

Comment: I have locked Debug.Assert and activated Resume and everything worked great. Thanks and Merry Christmas.